PuppeteerSharp fails to display base64-encoded images in PDF output
I'm using PuppeteerSharp to convert an HTML page to a PDF in my .NET project. While the images are visible when I view the HTML in a browser, they do not appear in the generated PDF. The images are embedded in the HTML as base64-encoded strings.
See minimal reproducible example below.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sample PDF with Base64 Images</h1>
    <p>This is a sample image that should appear in the PDF.</p>
     <p>Some long text here.</p>
    <img loading="lazy" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA..." alt="Sample Image">
</body>
</html>

Further observations made:

some other HTML documetns worked fine
only some images were not shown
only images outside of viewport seem to be affected


Without the site and a [mcve], only you could have answered this.

I've posted this question along with its answer because none of the existing Stack Overflow responses or GitHub issues addressed this. I'm sharing this as a note for anyone who might face the same issue in the future, in hopes that it will save someone's time.

See Should the "Can I answer my own question?" guide mention question quality standards?. The question still needs to be complete and answerable on its own merit, disregarding your self-answer. This question doesn't abide by normal quality standards, and is just a strawman only you can knock down. Any number of things could cause this error beyond the answer you gave and without the actual page, it's anyone's guess.

Thanks for adding me as a bad example and downvote.
I added minimal reproducible example as requested.
Maybe self-answered questions should have its own category then?
The minimal reproducible example in this case was a toguh one, because the HTML documents I tried had more than 2K lines of code which is not exactly minimal. As I mentioned again, I posted this, because this particular edge was not mentioned anywhere. Now when I know the solution, the minimal reproducible example is too obvious. Maybe I was wrong to psot it here and blog post would be better.

The example helps. No, they should abide by the same standards as any other question so they're useful to future readers and other answerers can feasibly weigh in on them. Actually, this sort of lazy loading question (or things not loading in general) shows up pretty regularly. Yes, that's the point of minimal examples, they make the problem/solution obvious. Most of the time you can solve your own problem just by minimizing the problem in preparation for asking about it. The most interesting questions are one that are minimal, yet still unclear, the rest mostly just need minimizing.

Then there are other questions that are literally impossible to answer since OP didn't provide any code, so it's all guesswork. Or provided a massive chunk of code and haven't minimized it, but the problem would be obvious if they did. Those are not good questions.

BTW even after your edit, the solution isn't clear so the problematic behavior still isn't reproducible. I don't see how stripping attributes would cause the images to load--nobody else would arrive at that solution. I suggest sharing the actual site and your code that runs on it. JS is necessary to load the images, but isn't part of this example.

Canonical: Puppeteer wait for all images to load then take screenshot

For those encountering similar issues, the problem was lazy loading. Images not initially visible on the page with lazy loading activated failed to render.
<img loading="lazy" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...">

Removing the lazy loading attribute from the image element resolved the issue, and PDF generation functioned properly once more.
